# EventKitUI view and edit problem!

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I try to to find a solution to do View and Edit of a the item from a tablview.
My application base on UITabBarController.

Each of the Bar items contain a class with a a couple of UIViews.
This is the first items of UITabBarController.

I done Add event from Apple sample code: SimpleEKDemo. Add Event working without any problem.

I tried to add View and Edit part to the code. I would able to select an items from tableView to edit the selected item.
But after I tried to add code from SimpleEKDemo to my code, I realized I have to add UINavigationController to the implement. So I did.

After I add that it's came to the items of UITabBarController. Also I even the Add Event didn't worked very well (I couldn't insert event name and location. but edit was working.

So I need to know:
1- Is it possible to implement Edit/View without using UINavigationController.
If yes please let me know a sample code.

2- If I must use UINavigationController.
Because I don't need UINavigationController to become it the first page and I don't need any bar added to my application. Is it possible it's appear in the application when I choose a item of tableView but appear alike that!

Snapshots:
https://public.me.com/alish (pict.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this issue last week. Finally I got the answer from apple's IOS document.
It suggest use one UIViewController for a screen.

This is some guide from apple's ios document([link text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)):
Note: If you want to divide a view hierarchy into multiple subareas and manage each one separately, use generic controller objects (custom objects descending from NSObject) instead of view controller objects to manage each subarea. Then use a single view controller object to manage the generic controller objects.

My solution:
1. Define xib file bookController.xib for a subview to manage books
2. Create a custom controller(inherit NSObject) BookController
3. Set the file owner to BookController in bookController.xib 
4. Create the view by loading from a xib file and associate with the custom controller object
BookController * bookController = ...
UIView * bookView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"bookView" owner: bookController options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0];
5. Switch view by add the view to display to the root controller's view as sub-view

Help this helps you~

// Create a customer controller
OneCategoryNavigationController * oneBookCategory = [[OneCategoryNavigationController alloc] initWithOrientation: orientation];

UIView * cellContentView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"OneCategoryBookNavigationView" owner: oneBookCategory options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0];

// load the book thumbnails after loading xib file
[oneBookCategory loadBookThumbnails];

// add the view to super view
[self.view addSubview: cellContentView];

Comment: thanks for your message. But I confused! Is it possible show me with snapshots or etc. with code?

Comment: A snapshot to associate xib file to controoler: http://postimage.org/image/2lk5cha1w/

Comment: thanks for your time. But I don't understand what do you mean! but thanks for  your favor :)

Comment: From my understanding, you want to use UITabBarController to control switching between multiple screen, each screen implements a certain feature. For the "event list" screen, you need switch between multiple views. Right? If so,  the sample code I provided can help manage the multiple view switching.

Comment: I'm sure it's Headache for you. But if possible please email to alishmac@gmail.com and if possible I'll discuss the issue in the email. If not possible for you, forget about it and don't worry. Again thanks for your kindly help!